# How to copy two sheets to a new workbook as value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to copy two specific sheets to a new workbook. The code works, but only the first one is copied as value, the second one is copied ad formula.

Does anyone knows how can both sheets be copied as value? Many thanks!! =D

```
Sub CopyTabsToNewWorkbook()

Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     
    'To unhide the tab
     Worksheets("EMEA & AM").Visible = xlSheetVisible
     Worksheets("CAT").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    
     Worksheets(Array("EMEA & AM", "CAT")).Copy

    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    With wbNew
        With .Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
        End With
        
        path = "https://Shared Link Path/" & "\"
        filename = Range("AP1")
        
        .SaveAs filename:=path & filename
        .Close savechanges:=False
     End With
     
     'To hide the tab
      Worksheets("EMEA & AM").Visible = xlSheetHidden
      Worksheets("CAT").Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Because this part only replaces the formulas with values in the first sheet `Worksheets(1)`

```
With .Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

If you want to do that with all worksheets in the new workbook you need to loop

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In wbNew.Worksheets
    With ws.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With    
Next ws
```

This will replace formulas in all worksheets you copied into the `wbNew` no matter how many worksheets you copied.

Comment: Dear Peh, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but still only the first sheet is being copied as value. When I use use exactly as you posted I get an error at '.SaveAs'

Comment: You get an error probably because you did not specify in which workbook and worksheet `Range("AP1")` is. If you do not define that Excel guesses and it might guess wrong. Always specify in which workbook a range is by using something like `wbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("AP1")` or where ever you expect that range to be.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
With .Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
End With

'convert the second sheet to value like you did for the first sheet
With .Worksheets(2).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
End With
```